# Do diagonal mecanum wheels require the rollers to cross the center of the robot

Tags: mobile-robot

I'm currently in the process of making some changes to my robot to use mecanum wheels. The kinematic models I've seen assume the 45 degree roller from one diagonal wheel to the other, crosses the center of the robot and I've also seen some frame designs which don't bother with this at all. Would there be any major implications if X alignment doesn't cross the center of the robot?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a diagram to illustrate?

Answer (score 2):

From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecanum_wheel), the wheel will generate a propelling force perpendicular to the roller axel.

Note the yellow box isn't the outline of the robot, just a box representing the mounting points of the wheels. So to your question, overlay your robot on the image and analyze whether the pivot points are what you want/desire.

[image]